# The way of using ''with honey color '' in sentence below

Tags: grammaticality

Plastic products that we make , are honey-colored. In this case can i say '' our product come out with honey color''. Did i use '' with honey color '' correctly in this sentences ?

Comment: why are you trying to use "with honey-colour" when you have already used "are honey-coloured" which is perfect?

Answer (score 1):

"With honey-colour" does not sound correct in this context.

I think you are trying to say:

> Our product is available **in** honey-colour.

If something is one colour only then we use "in". The preposition "with" is used to show that something is accompanied by something else. We would only say "with honey-colour" in a sentence if we were indicating that the colour was in addition to another colour, for example:

> Our product is black with honey-colour.

This also implies that black is the dominant colour but "honey" is perhaps a highlight. You can see this in other similar expressions such as "*tea with honey*", which would suggest a little bit of honey has been added to the tea - not the other way around.

If by "come out" you mean that this colour option has been *newly* released and want to make that apparent in your statement, you could say:

> Our product is *now* available in honey-colour.

OR

> Our product has just been released in honey-colour.

(Note I use the BrEng spelling of "colour", for US audience you are correct to use "color")